# Combining a query into an existing JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am having some difficulties combining two `SELECT` queries. One is a basic query the other is a `JOIN`. I want to `JOIN` my `$stmt_id` query with the `JOIN` query.

`$stmt_id` query...

```
$stmt_id = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3,4,5)");
if ( !$stmt_id || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Userid SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
//if(!$stmt_id->bind_param('i', $userid)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
    //    die('Userid SELECT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt_id->error));
    //}
if(!$stmt_id->execute()) {
        die('Userid SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt_id->error));

    $stmt_id->store_result();
}
$stmt_id->bind_result($userid);

while ($stmt_id->fetch()) {
    echo $userid;
}
```

This is my `JOIN` query, where I want to add the `$stmt_id` query into:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = ?
ORDER BY up.ordering");
if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User/Player SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User/Player SELECT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User/Player SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $username, $playername);
```

I know the uquery has to include the id in the `SELECT` part of the query, but I'm not sure how to modify this line..

```
  WHERE u.id = ?
```

To include this from the `$stmt_id` query...

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3,4,5)")
```

Here is what I have tried and am stuck on...

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.id = ?
ORDER BY up.ordering");
if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User/Player SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User/Player SELECT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User/Player SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $username, $playername);
```

Comment: Why not simply add `AND u.group IN (3,4,5)` to your second query?

Comment: So like this? `prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername, AND u.group IN (3,4,5)` ?

Comment: @Stavr00 or do you mean here? `WHERE u.id AND u.group IN (3,4,5)= ?`

Comment: `SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u  
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.group IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY up.ordering`

Comment: So, I take out this part? `WHERE u.id` ?